# Constraint Check for 10 Digit Character use for Postal Code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with a `Char(10)` column type, named `postal Code` and I need a Constraint check for all values just be 10 digits like `1234567890` and nothing else, I use the following:

```
CONSTRAINT [CH_PCDigit] CHECK ( [PostalCode] LIKE '%[^0-9]%'),
CONSTRAINT [CH_PCLength] CHECK ( LEN([PostalCode])=10)
```

but not worked correctly, why? and what is your suggestion? is there any way to merge this 2 constraint with one?

And what about if I want a Postal Code like this: `12345-54321` mean: 5digit-5digit? (Also Type must be `Char(11)`).

Does any one know any good source for Rgex or Constraint Check in SQl?

Answer (score 10):

SQL Server TSQL does not support full blown RegEx's. You can do what you want in a single constraint like so:

```
CONSTRAINT [CH_PCDigit] 
    CHECK ([PostalCode] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

or better:

```
CONSTRAINT [CH_PCDigit] 
    CHECK ([PostalCode] LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 10))
```

If you want to allow dashes:

```
CREATE table  ChkTest
(
    PostalCode char(10) not null
        CONSTRAINT [CH_PCDigit]  
    CHECK ([PostalCode] LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9,-]', 10)) 
)

-- Test Code...

insert into ChkTest 
select '1234567890'

insert into ChkTest 
select '123456780'

insert into ChkTest 
select '12345678y0'

insert into ChkTest 
select '12345678901'

select * from ChkTest

insert into ChkTest 
select '12345-8901'
```

Comment: So `[0-9]{10}` is not supported in SQL Server ? :O

Comment: Will that allow doubled dashes, like '1234--8901'?

Comment: @MitchWheat: I don't have SQL Server running at home.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one that accepts both U.S. Zip Code and Canada Postal Code.

```
CONSTRAINT CH_PCDigit
CHECK (PostalCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR 
       PostalCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR
       PostalCode LIKE '[A-Y][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]')
```

Comment: (and note that you'd want to use the '~' operator for regex in postgres)

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use isnumeric, split big number:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
pc CHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT pc_c CHECK ( 
       LEN(pc) = 10 AND 
       ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(pc,1,5))=1 AND 
       ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(pc,6,5))=1)
)
```