# SQL Server 2012 failing to import ZIP from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel file which I want to import into a SQL Server table, there is a zipcode column which the importer sets it as `nvarchar(255)` which may have either `xxxxx-yyyy` or `xxxxx` data. The shorter data gets always imported as null, the edit mapping doesn't give any feasible option. Running this form SSMS, the Excel I had to lower to 97-2003 version as I don't see an option there for later versions, I tried the CSV no success, setting a format in the Excel column no go.

I solved it by importing to Access and then to SQL or with a Perl script replacing the dash to `_` and then replacing it back in the SQL but that is too clumsy.

What am I missing from importing it the right way?

Comment: it's not clear to me what failure you are getting, or what tool you are using to do the import.

Comment: I've imported Zip/Zip+4 to MS SQL from XL successfully by using the custom number format `[>99999]00000-0000;00000` in the worksheet before attempting the import.[edit] You also need to strip out all of the hyphens so the zip+4 get formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this from [SSDT using SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3046/sql-server-integration-services-data-type-conversion-testing/), and use the [data type conversion task](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-ssis-data-types/), or you can build the table with a specified data type already set, and then you will have no issues on the import - **ZipeCode is Varchar (10)**, See below editing the table creation data types in import export[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ9gd.jpg)

Or via leveraging the Excel connection manager in a full SSIS project.
[image]

[Don't forget to add a constraint on that zip code column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375767/constraint-check-for-10-digit-character-use-for-postal-code)